# is there a quick way to easily set up a pen and paper game online

Tags: online-roleplaying

OnineI was wondering since i found I want to play dnd. only problem is I have no one to play with. so I tried going online to play on roll20 and some other sites but they always say tomorrow or in a week. That's not what I'm looking for I'm looking for an easy quick So basically all I'm asking does anyone know a way to quickly and easily set up and play a game of dnd (when your a person with no friends)